# WIndows subsystem for Linux 'Get' button is disabled

Tags: windows-store-app, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install Ubuntu on windows using Windows subsystem for linux, but on store the button is grey, how can I enable it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to install Ubuntu on windows using Windows subsystem for
>   linux, but on store the button is grey

You are trying to install the Windows 10 1709+ Ubuntu WSL on a Windows 10 1703 installation.  **That will not be possible.**

[image]

What you actually want to do, if you want to install WSL today on a Windows 10 1511+ to Windows 10 1703 installation simply do the following:

1. Enable **Developer Mode**

[image]

2. Install **Windows Subsystem for Linux Beta**

[image]

3. Reboot

> how can I enable it?

You cannot enable it.  What you have found can only be installed on a Windows 10 build 16215 or higher installation.  You should simply wait until 1709 is released or use an Insider Preview build of RS3 (aka 1709) if you cannot wait.